# Printf in C (types)

Tags: c, types, printf, scanf

I just started programming in C. And I don't really understand the following code:

```
printf("%zu",i);
```

or instead of `%zu` what are the other things that I can write (I know that they depend on the type of i) and which one is for what?

Comment: `%zu` is used for `size_t`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Format_placeholders

Comment: Why not try something a bit radical and out of the box, like reading some documentation?

Comment: GNU C Library [12.12.3 Table of Output Conversions](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Table-of-Output-Conversions.html#Table-of-Output-Conversions)

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fprintf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes `unsigned size_t i` and prints it to the stdout.

Comment: `size_t` *is* unsigned.

Comment: @MartinR, I wanted to clarify the 'u'

Answer (score 3):

It's a format modifier for `siz_t` and `size_t` is unsigned.

```
printf("%zu\n", x);  // print unsigned decimal
printf("%zx\n", x);  // print hexadecimal
printf("%zd\n", y);  // print signed decimal
```